# How to get the result from the Facebook API?

Tags: c#, json, facebook

I got a problem with my Code over here and I'm Googling around for like 3 hours now.

I'm just doing a FQL-Query and I'm trying to read the result. But unfortunately. I don't know how.

```
var fbclient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

            dynamic result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbclient.Get("fql", new
            {
                q = new[]
                {
                    "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = me()",
                    "SELECT unread_count FROM mailbox_folder WHERE folder_id = 4 AND viewer_id = me()",
                    "SELECT is_unread FROM notification WHERE recipient_id = me()",
                    "SELECT unread FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to = me()"
                }
            });

            string name = "";

            foreach (dynamic data in result.data)
            {
                name = data.name;
            }
```

And the last part (`foreach`) doesn't work out - was just the last thing I tried.

Comment: I don't have enough information here to provide anything useful. See http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html for more information.

Comment: I dont know what else I should add. That's all it takes. It's an FQL-Multi-Query what gets me an JSON Array (somehow) and i just need to know how to read those arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Answering my own question now. It took a while but i finally figured out how to get to the Infos out of an FQL-Multi-Query. For those who search the same:

```
dynamic result = fbclient.Get("fql", new
        {
            q = new[]
        {
            "SELECT unread_count FROM mailbox_folder WHERE folder_id = 0 AND viewer_id = me()",
            "SELECT is_unread FROM notification WHERE recipient_id = me()",
            "SELECT unread FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to = me()"
        }
        });

        var unread_messages = result["data"][0]["fql_result_set"][0]["unread_count"];
        var notifications = result["data"][1]["fql_result_set"];
        var open_friendRequests = result["data"][2]["fql_result_set"];
```

That's all I've ever wanted ;o)

Best regards,

Danny